# Como evitar repetição de código que faz a mesma coisa para IDs diferentes?

Tags: javascript, html

Existe uma função *onClick* Javascript para cada "Mostrar mais".
Esta função altera a visibilidade da div para visible  a qual o padrão é hidden.

Porém, por mais simples que seja, o código ficou grande demais.
Há alguma maneira de encurtar ou diminuir isso?

Exemplo: apenas um botão de "Mostrar mais" e uma div? Então a cada clique no "Mostrar mais" mostrasse uma div, uma embaixo da outra?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  input{
    margin-top: 5px;
}

  input#abreBt{
    margin-left: 100px;
}

  input#bt1{
    margin-left: 50px;
}

  hr{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" name="abreBt" id="abreBt" value="Mostrar mais" onClick="javascript: abreBts1();" />
<div name="divHidden" id="divHidden" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <input type="button" name="bt1" id="bt1" value="+" />
  <input type="button" name="bt2" id="bt2" value="-" /> 
  <input type="button" name="bt3" id="bt3" value="Novo" style="width: 100px;" />
  <input type="button" name="bt4" id="bt4" value="+" /><br><hr><br>
</div>

<input type="button" name="abreBt" id="abreBt" value="Mostrar mais" onClick="javascript: abreBts2();" />
<div name="divHidden" id="divHidden2" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <input type="button" name="bt1" id="bt1" value="+" />
  <input type="button" name="bt2" id="bt2" value="-" /> 
  <input type="button" name="bt3" id="bt3" value="Novo" style="width: 100px;" />
  <input type="button" name="bt4" id="bt4" value="+" /><br><hr><br>
</div>

<input type="button" name="abreBt" id="abreBt" value="Mostrar mais" onClick="javascript: abreBts3();" />
<div name="divHidden" id="divHidden3" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <input type="button" name="bt1" id="bt1" value="+" />
  <input type="button" name="bt2" id="bt2" value="-" /> 
  <input type="button" name="bt3" id="bt3" value="Novo" style="width: 100px;" />
  <input type="button" name="bt4" id="bt4" value="+" /><br><hr><br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<script>
  function abreBts1(){
    document.getElementById('divHidden').style.visibility="visible";
}

  function abreBts2(){
    document.getElementById('divHidden2').style.visibility="visible";
}

  function abreBts3(){
    document.getElementById('divHidden3').style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Olá! Você pode colocar na sua pergunta o código que você está usando para fazer sua div? Leia mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Sugiro também que você separe essa pergunta em 3 (crie outras duas perguntas com suas outras dúvidas) - é melhor para você, que está perguntando, é melhor pra quem vai responder, e é melhor para o site.

Comment: Eu fiz o código e acabei esquecendo de colocar na pergunta...

Comment: Bacana! Não sei se está claro ainda o que você pretende fazer (talvez façam perguntas) mas já está muito melhor! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Editado] Adicionei a classe .some e ela é responsável agora por adicionar o visibility, dessa forma é possível pegar sempre o primeiro elemento dessa classe e remover a mesma. Qualquer dúvida comente abaixo.

```js
jQuery('input').click(function(){
  jQuery(jQuery('.some').get(0)).removeClass('some')
});
```

```css
  input{
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.some{
  visibility: hidden;
}

  input#abreBt{
    margin-left: 100px;
}

  input#bt1{
    margin-left: 50px;
}

  hr{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="button" name="abreBt" id="abreBt" value="Mostrar mais" />
<div name="divHidden" id="divHidden" class="some">
  <input type="button" name="bt1" id="bt1" value="+" />
  <input type="button" name="bt2" id="bt2" value="-" /> 
  <input type="button" name="bt3" id="bt3" value="Novo" style="width: 100px;" />
  <input type="button" name="bt4" id="bt4" value="+" /><br><hr><br>
</div>
</div>
<div class="t">
  <div name="divHidden" id="divHidden2"  class="some">
  <input type="button" name="bt1" id="bt1" value="+" />
  <input type="button" name="bt2" id="bt2" value="-" /> 
  <input type="button" name="bt3" id="bt3" value="Novo" style="width: 100px;" />
  <input type="button" name="bt4" id="bt4" value="+" /><br><hr><br>
  </div>
</div>
<div>

<div name="divHidden" id="divHidden3"  class="some">
  <input type="button" name="bt1" id="bt1" value="+" />
  <input type="button" name="bt2" id="bt2" value="-" /> 
  <input type="button" name="bt3" id="bt3" value="Novo" style="width: 100px;" />
  <input type="button" name="bt4" id="bt4" value="+" /><br><hr><br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não sei se acabei sendo pouco direto sobre o que gostaria de fazer, mas vou tentar de novo.
A minha ideia era só utilizar um botão "Mostrar mais", então cada vez que eu clicasse no nele aparecesse uma div a cada vez que clicado.
Desculpe, não consigo lembrar de nenhum exemplo para usar

Comment: Entendi irei editar minha resposta!

Comment: Pronto, veja se resolve!

Comment: @MrVanDaime alterei o código referente a resposta, qualquer duvida me comunique.

Comment: era isso que mesmo que eu estava procurando, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

primeiro passo, é adicionar alguma referencia a `div` no `input`, para tal você pode aplicar um `data-custom`.

```js
(function () {
  var selecionado = document.querySelector(".visivel");
  document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("bt-titulo")) {
      var conteudoId = event.target.dataset.conteudo;
      var conteudo = document.getElementById(conteudoId);    
      if (selecionado) 
        selecionado.classList.remove("visivel");
      selecionado = conteudo;
      selecionado.classList.add("visivel");
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
.div-conteudo {
  display: none;
}

.visivel {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="titulos">
  <input type="button" id="titulo1" class="bt-titulo" data-conteudo="conteudo1" value="Mostrar Conteudo 1" />
  <input type="button" id="titulo2" class="bt-titulo" data-conteudo="conteudo2" value="Mostrar Conteudo 2" />
  <input type="button" id="titulo3" class="bt-titulo" data-conteudo="conteudo3" value="Mostrar Conteudo 3" />
</div>
<div id="conteudos">
  <div id="conteudo1" class="div-conteudo visivel">Conteudo 1</div>
  <div id="conteudo2" class="div-conteudo">Conteudo 2</div>
  <div id="conteudo3" class="div-conteudo">Conteudo 3</div>
</div>
```

Note que no exemplo acima, o evento `click` está associado ao `document` e não aos `input`, mesmo mesmo que adicione um `input` e sua respectiva `div` de forma dinâmica, o comportamento irá continuar consistente.

por fim, um exemplo um pouco mais complexo.:

```js
(function () {
  var selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
  var selecionado = document.querySelector(".visivel");
  var onTituloClick = function (event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("bt-titulo")) {
      var conteudoId = event.target.dataset.conteudo;
      var conteudo = document.getElementById(conteudoId);    
      if (selecionado) selecionado.classList.remove("visivel");
      if (selected) selected.classList.remove("selected");
      selecionado = conteudo;
      selecionado.classList.add("visivel");
      selected = event.target;
      selected.classList.add("selected");
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", onTituloClick);
  if (selected) {
    onTituloClick({ target: selected });
  }
})();
```

```css
.div-conteudo {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #00796B;
  border-top: 1px solid #009688;
  background-color: #009688;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  color: white;
}

.visivel {
  display: block;
}

#titulos .bt-titulo {
  background-color: #4DB6AC;
  border: 1px solid #00796B;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #009688;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

#titulos .bt-titulo:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
}

#titulos .bt-titulo:not(.selected) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00796B;
}

#titulos .bt-titulo:hover {
  background-color: #26A69A;
}

#titulos .bt-titulo.selected {
  background-color: #009688;
}

#titulos:after, #conteudos:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="titulos">
  <input type="button" id="titulo1" class="bt-titulo selected" data-conteudo="conteudo1" value="Mostrar Conteudo 1" />
  <input type="button" id="titulo2" class="bt-titulo" data-conteudo="conteudo2" value="Mostrar Conteudo 2" />
  <input type="button" id="titulo3" class="bt-titulo" data-conteudo="conteudo3" value="Mostrar Conteudo 3" />
</div>
<div id="conteudos">
  <div id="conteudo1" class="div-conteudo">Conteudo 1</div>
  <div id="conteudo2" class="div-conteudo">Conteudo 2</div>
  <div id="conteudo3" class="div-conteudo">Conteudo 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito legal, provavelmente irei me espelhar no futuro, meus conhecimentos em javascript ainda não estão muito apurados, mas mesmo assim obrigado.